# Questions about Setuptools and alternatives

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, pip

I've seen a good bit of setuptools bashing on the internets lately. Most recently, I read James Bennett's [On packaging](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/14/packaging/) post on why no one should be using setuptools. From my time in #python on Freenode, I know that there are a few souls there who absolutely detest it. I would count myself among them, but I do actually use it.

I've used setuptools for enough projects to be aware of its deficiencies, and I would prefer something better. I don't particularly like the egg format and how it's deployed. With all of setuptools' problems, I haven't found a better alternative.

My understanding of tools like [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) is that it's meant to be an easy_install replacement (not setuptools). In fact, pip uses some setuptools components, right?

Most of my packages make use of a setuptools-aware setup.py, which declares all of the dependencies. When they're ready, I'll build an sdist, bdist, and bdist_egg, and upload them to pypi.

If I wanted to switch to using pip, what kind of changes would I need to make to rid myself of easy_install dependencies? Where are the dependencies declared? I'm guessing that I would need to get away from using the egg format, and provide just source distributions. If so, how do i generate the egg-info directories? or do I even need to?

How would this change my usage of virtualenv? Doesn't virtualenv use easy_install to manage the environments?

How would this change my usage of the setuptools provided "develop" command? Should I not use that? What's the alternative?

I'm basically trying to get a picture of what my development workflow will look like.

Before anyone suggests it, I'm not looking for an OS-dependent solution. I'm mainly concerned with debian linux, but deb packages are not an option, for the reasons Ian Bicking outlines [here](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/14/a-few-corrections-to-on-packaging/).

Comment: Some of the history of `setuptools`, `distutils`, `distutils2`, `pip`, and friends is discussed [here](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/distutils2-vs-pip).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

pip uses Setuptools, and doesn't require any changes to packages.  It actually installs packages with Setuptools, using:

```
python -c 'import setuptools; __file__="setup.py"; execfile(__file__)' \
    install \
    --single-version-externally-managed
```

Because it uses that option (`--single-version-externally-managed`) it doesn't ever install eggs as zip files, doesn't support multiple simultaneously installed versions of software, and the packages are installed flat (like `python setup.py install` works if you use only distutils).  Egg metadata is still installed.  pip also, like easy_install, downloads and installs all the requirements of a package.

*In addition* you can also use a requirements file to add other packages that should be installed in a batch, and to make version requirements more exact (without putting those exact requirements in your `setup.py` files).  But if you don't make requirements files then you'd use it just like easy_install.

For your `install_requires` I don't recommend any changes, unless you have been trying to create very exact requirements there that are known to be good.  I think there's a limit to how exact you can usefully be in `setup.py` files about versions, because you can't really know what the future compatibility of new libraries will be like, and I don't recommend you try to predict this.  Requirement files are an alternate place to lay out conservative version requirements.

You can still use `python setup.py develop`, and in fact if you do `pip install -e svn+http://mysite/svn/Project/trunk#egg=Project` it will check that out (into `src/project`) and run `setup.py develop` on it.  So that workflow isn't any different really.

If you run pip verbosely (like `pip install -vv`) you'll see a lot of the commands that are run, and you'll probably recognize most of them.

Comment: I like to know more detail about that "In addition you can also use a requirements file to add other packages that should be installed in a batch, and to make version requirements more exact".

Answer (score 3):

For starters, pip is really new. New, incomplete and largely un-tested in the real world.

It shows great promise but until such time as it can do everything that easy_install/setuptools can do it's not likely to catch on in a big way, certainly not in the corporation.

Easy_install/setuptools is big and complex - and that offends a lot of people. Unfortunately there's a really good reason for that complexity which is that it caters for a huge number of different use-cases. My own is supporting a large ( > 300 ) pool of desktop users, plus a similar sized grid with a frequently updated application. The notion that we could do this by allowing every user to install from source is ludicrous - eggs have proved themselves a reliable way to distribute my project.

My advice: Learn to use setuptools - it's really a wonderful thing. Most of the people who hate it do not understand it, or simply do not have the use-case for as full-featured distribution system.

:-)

Comment: Honestly, I feel like I know setuptools fairly well. There have been some gripes with it.. mainly with how it handles deployment of the egg files. It works well enough for me right now, but there are lots people in the python community (whose opinions I respect) who will simply not touch it.

Comment: While pip is new, if it works for you then it works for you -- it's not terribly *subtle*.  Mostly like easy_install, it finds packages, downloads them, and installs them (by invoking python setup.py install, or python setup.py develop if you use -e).

Comment: `setuptools`, is not maintained and does not support python 3. Probably being replaced by `distribute`

Comment: @sorin The (modern) reality is entirely opposite: `setuptools` _is_ maintained, and _only_ supports Python 3, not Python 2; read https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/python%202%20sunset.html#python-2-sunset

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this in April 2014.  Be conscious of the date on anything written about Python packaging, distribution or installation.  It looks like there's been some lessening of factiousness, improvement in implementations, PEP-standardizing and unifying of fronts in the last, say, three years.

For instance, the [Python Packaging Authority](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-python-packaging-authority-pypa) is "a working group that maintains many of the relevant projects in Python packaging."

The `python.org` [Python Packaging User Guide](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) has [Tool Recommendations](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/current.html) and [The Future of Python Packaging](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/future.html) sections.

`distribute` was a branch of `setuptools` that was remerged in June 2013.  The guide says, "Use `setuptools` to define projects and create Source Distributions."

As of PEP 453 and Python 3.4, the guide recommends, "Use `pip` to install Python packages from PyPI," and `pip` is included with Python 3.4 and installed in virtualenvs by `pyvenv`, which is also included.  You might find the [PEP 453 "rationale" section](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/#rationale) interesting.

There are also new and newish tools mentioned in the guide, including [`wheel`](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-wheel) and [`buildout`](http://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html#buildout).

I'm glad I read both of the following technical/semi-political histories.

By Martijn Faassen in 2009: [A History of Python Packaging](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/a-history-of-python-packaging.html).

And by Armin Ronacher in June 2013 (the title is not serious): [Python Packaging: Hate, hate, hate everywhere](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/22/hate-hate-hate-everywhere/).