# Does precondition assertion testing replace assumptions in a function specification or vice versa?

Tags: python, testing, assert, assertion

I'm confused as when to exactly use assertion testing in my python functions. If I specify assumptions regarding the input arguments to a function, should I assume that correct input is being fed to the function or should I use assertions to check the conditions on the input args enumerated in the specification?

Comment: The "Pythonic" way is to generally do things assuming everything's fine and use `try/except` blocks to handle any false assumptions.

Comment: Related: [What are acceptable use-cases for python's `assert` statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142202/3821804)

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing "public" function, I believe that pythonic way would be to check arguments (using `if`, not `assert`), and, if they're invalid, raise exception with type and info / message designed to provide as much info as possible.

If you're writing function designed for internal use, then using `assert` to check the arguments seems to be good idea for me.

Comment: I agree, however, I'd replace the term "internal functions" with "test functions" as assert in live code is generally a bad thing.

Comment: is that because it halts execution? But then so does try/except.

Comment: @Ned: I meant what I wrote -- functions, which are not part of the module's or class's interface. What do you mean by "live code"?

Comment: @derpfoo - True, try/except halts execution in the same way, however assertions mean that if this is not true that the entire flow should exit (I know that's not how they're programmed, but realistically, that's what assert technically means.) It's better to subclass Exception and throw the appropriate Exception when something isn't expected which allows for different error handling.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Live code means code that runs in production. Whether it's part of the class's interface or a private method, it's insanely hard to guarantee things to the point you'd want to use assert. It's far better to use Exception subclasses so client code can handle error cases appropriately.

edit: Live code generally means code that takes input from an external source and thus can generate different outputs and executions than might have been considered by the programmer.