# When was Python's .egg format introduced?

Tags: python, setuptools

What is the history of setuptools? When was its first release with support for the `.egg` format?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368636/questions-about-setuptools-and-alternatives ?

Comment: @HaloWebMaster How is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's since [setuptools 0.6b1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6b1), released 2006-05-12.

From the changelog:

> Feature Highlights:
>
> * Create `Python Eggs`_ -
>      a single-file importable distribution format